# Cancel LostFocus in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a WPF Textbox, that I want to check that the text value is correct before I allow it to lose keyboard/focus.

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0"
Text="{Binding Input, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<b:Interaction.Triggers>
    <b:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
        <b:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding LostFocusCommand}" />
    </b:EventTrigger>
 </b:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In command how to cancel lost focus?

Comment: Honestly, this pattern is not very well suited for stock WPF MVVM. It's much easier to implement IDataErrorInfo, and refrain from saving any updates that do not pass muster. Let the user put incorrect data into the control, but force them to fix before any updates occur. To do what you want you really need custom controls that are designed for this kind of validation, or for specific inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` event and use a `TriggerAction` that passes the `EventArgs` to the command. [MvvmLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight) has an `EventToCommand` action that does this:

```
<TextBox ... xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight">
    <b:Interaction.Triggers>
        <b:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewLostKeyboardFocus">
            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LostFocusCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </b:EventTrigger>
    </b:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

**View Model:**

```
LostFocusCommand = new RelayCommand<KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs>(args => 
{
    //...

    args.Handled = true;
});
```

Comment: value is null in PreviewLostKeyboardFocus

Comment: You mean in the Execute method of the command? Then you haven't used the EventToCommand as per my suggestion. Did you copy my answer?